# VBA to paste from one column to another?

Tags: excel, vba

I need code for the below requirement, wherein the below code is not working:

```
Sub sample48()
Worksheets("Sheet").Select
 Range("AG1").Select
    Range("A1:AQ1").Autofilter Field:=33, Criteria1:="COD*"
  Range("AG:AG").Value = Range("AM:AM").Value
End Sub
```

I need to filter a word called `**COD**` in column AG, and then I need to copy and paste values from Column AG to Column AM only for the those filtered line items.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in excel you can copy from filtered area, but when you are pasting, data will not paste on filtered(visible) cells, instead pasted continuously. There is 2 way to do your task:

1: Use loop

```
Sub MyCopyPaste()
    Dim RngCnt As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("AM" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each RngCnt In Range("AM1:AM" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Range("AG" & RngCnt.Row).Value = Range("AM" & RngCnt.Row).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

2: Without Loop

If in some case you don't want use loop or vba, you should create another column and put an ID number into it. This column will used to sort the worksheet to retain rows order to original. Then create another column with name custom_Order and after filtering, put numbers into it, then show all data and sort worksheet based on custom_order and then filter it. In this case all your expected rows will be filter and come continuously and you can easily copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub sample48()

 Range("A1:AQ1").AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria1:="COD*"
 Range("AG:AG").Copy
 Range("AM:AM").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

This does quite literaly what you asked:

- filter your range
- copy colmun AG (because it is filtered, only filtered values are copied)
- paste filtered values in AM

you can not use an equation on a range for an entire range. Also, judging by your description, I assume your equation had to be the other way around.

Comment: While this may answer the question, try to add some explanation for better understanding.